# How to create proper MR after some mistake?

Tags: git

I have a small problem. (Maybe check the bottom first, wasn't sure how to best described it)

I have branch x, branch y and branch master. X and y are not protected and I can force push to them.

I have created some work in branch x and now I have merge request to master.

Then I have created branch y from x and did some other work on that branch. When I finished my work on y, some changes were made in branch x, so I decided that I will rebase those changes to my branch y.

But I have done wrong! I have rebased y into x! After some cursing I managed to create new commit for x where I've reverted my changes.

And after that I've done git rebase from x to y like I wanted.

**And now things got complicated.**

Somehow, I don't know how (or don't remember) I lost my changes in branch y. It looks like x without changes. So I did git reset HEAD~ in branch y and created new commit with previous changes.

So now I have branch x and y like I wanted to have them with successful rebase on y.

**And here we come to my problem :)**

When I now create merge request with y on my master it looks ok. Like x + y. Everything fine.

But I want to create MR not on master but on x. I want to merge my y to x, so other people can look at it and do code review.

But here I don't have every changes I have made on y! Why? What can I do if I want to show proper MR?

Comment: Are `X` and `Y` shared and/or protected branches, or are they your own branches? Are you allowed to force push either of them?

Comment: They are not protected, I can force push to them.

Answer (score 2):

> But I have done wrong! I have rebased y into x! After some cursing...

One of the great things about Git is that once you commit something, it's locked in. It's simple to go back to any previous state by checking out a previous commit. If you like that commit you could re-point any branch to it, which I assume is what you want to do in your case. All you have to do is find out where you were before:

```
git reflog # find the commit ID where you want to go back to

git reset --hard <desired-commit-id> # make your current branch point to this commit
```

Also, this may seem nitpicky, but I think it's worth mentioning your use of the phrase "rebased y into x". (Maybe it was a typo, but I think pointing it out may help highlight why it matters.) In Git-speak, if you are working on branch X and wish to bring in the changes from branch Y, you can either:

1. `merge` branch Y *into* branch X
2. `rebase` branch X *onto* branch Y

In both of those cases you are modifying branch `X`, but in different ways. Perhaps the merge is a little more obvious of what's happening, as you see a merge commit in the graph and changes from both sides are applied together. With rebase, first X gets set to exactly Y, and then each commit on X that is not on (or *reachable* by) Y, gets *replayed*, in order, "on top of" that starting point, which is Y. (This is why we say "onto".) With rebase your history will stay linear without adding a merge commit (by default).

> ...I managed to create new commit for x where I've reverted my changes... Somehow, I don't know how (or don't remember) I lost my changes in branch y.

When you `revert`, you are undoing changes with a new commit. Additionally, if you undo changes and try to bring back in the same commit IDs, they will be ignored because they already exist on the branch. To bring them in a second time you either need to "revert the revert" or change the commit IDs and bring them in again. This is the likely explanation for why the changes seemed to have vanished, even though they were still in the history.

> But I want to create MR not on master but on x. I want to merge my y to x, so other people can look at it and do code review.

Since these are your own branches, I would recommend just rewriting them both to how you wanted them in the first place, force push them back out and setup the MR for review. You could use the above `git reset --hard` commands to set both branches `X` and `Y` back to how you had them before you attempted the rebase, and then:

```
git switch Y # checkout Y
git rebase X # Update Y with the new commit(s) on X
git push --force-with-lease # force push Y so you can do a clean MR from Y to X
```